# change date format of date entered

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using javascript and I'm trying to change the format of my date entered. So far the code from online has it as below but I'm obviously doing something wrong because its not displaying in the format that I wish to have.

```
$(function () {
     $("#MainContent_PStart, #PStart").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true });
     $("#MainContent_PEnd, #PEnd").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true });
     $("#format").change(function () {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker("YYYY-MM-DD", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
     });
});
```

Comment: Could you: i) show us the current format of the dates ii) show us the expected result iii) define *its not displaying in format i want it*? Your question is too vague.

Comment: Current format = MM-DD-YYYY. I need YYYY-MM-DD. Currently the date is being selected, just not displaying in the format i want it.

Comment: Can you show your html element?  because what `#format` refers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("#MainContent_PStart, #PStart").datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to update the format of a datepicker, [from the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

Be careful, [the format string is case sensitive](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate):, as `mm` and `MM` don't mean the same thing.

*Edit*: [Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k8qtImcjGiQrwgzrysLK?p=preview) showing how to dynamically update the date format of a date picker.

Comment: The above isn't not working. the date is still being displayed as MM-DD-YYYY

Comment: Woops! Edited the answer with the correct setter method call.

Comment: still not working man..

these are the libraries i referenced:
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>